# Optimizing updating css classes for array of HTMLLIElement's

Tags: css, arrays, typescript, optimization

I have an array of HTMLLIElement that get's it's CSS class set based on a search input value. As soon as the array size becomes large it starts to lock and slow down, and I wonder how to optimize it's execution. I believe the comparison on each li elements text is what makes it slow. Code Follows:

```
// Takes the input, get the LI elements in it's context and converts them to an array of HTMLLIElement
const searchValue = myHappySeachInput.toLowerCase();
const selectListItems = myHappySelectList.querySelectorAll("li");
const myHappyArray = Array.from(selectListItems);

// ForEach element in the array do a comparison of the (beginning) search input against the innerText 
// and add/remove css class accordingly.
myHappyArray.forEach((li: HTMLLIElement) => {
          const label = li.querySelector("label");
          const text = label ? label.innerText.toLowerCase() : "";

          if (text.indexOf(searchValue) < 0) {
              li.classList.add("display-none");
          } else {
              li.classList.remove("display-none");
          }
      });
```

Hope there's a better way to do this. Thanks for reading and have a nice day!

**EDIT:** Thanks to CBroe, I focused on separating the look-up and assignment and ended up with something like this:

```
myHappyArray.forEach((li) => li.classList.add("display-none"));
const matchingLiElements = myHappyArray.filter((li) => li.querySelector("label")?.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue));
matchingLiElements.forEach((li) => li.classList.remove("display-none"));
```

It's not perfect, because we still need update all array elements css class every time, but filtering and re-assigning only on the matching elements already reduced the time by 80-90%.

Comment: "Large" meaning what - hundreds of items, thousands, more?

Comment: Not sure why you'd be looping over the `li`, only to then inside the loop select a `label` inside them - and not select `li label` to loop over to begin with? (Can there be more than one label inside an item?)

Comment: You might not want to do the `label.innerText.toLowerCase()` part on every search again, but determine these values once, and store them somewhere for further use. I'd put them into an array on initialization of the whole thing, array index corresponding to the index of the `li` as found by querySelectorAll.

Comment: 1. Up to a few hundreds it perform ok, but when it reaches over thousand it will slow. 2. Still need to set the CSS class on the li element, even thought we do the comparison on the label text but I think there's always only 1 label for each li 3. I'll try that, maybe comparing that way is faster. Thought might not be possible because the list changes dynamically.

Comment: Yeah, then you'd have to update your look-up-array accordingly, when the list content changes. How simple or complex that might be, depends on those changes - do only new items get added, or do items get removed, or even manipulated.

Comment: Did an update and made it function okay!